# Slice decimal point numbers dynamically

Tags: javascript, regex, split, slice

I have some decimal point numbers.

They are all 10 digits decimal point numbers as `String`

I'd like to slice them as `0` and `non-zero`.

```
"0.0000001234" => "0.000000", "1234" 
"0.0012345678" => "0.00", "12345678"
"0.0000123456" => "0.0000", "123456"
```

I've read about `slice()` or `split()`, but my problem is dynamic, so I can't solve it.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: regex is your friend.

Comment: `"0.0000001234".match(/^(0+(?:\.0+))([1-9]\d*)$/)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split`

```
 (^0+(?:\.0+)?)
```

[image]

```js
let slicer = (str) =>{
  return str.split(/(^0+(?:\.0+)?)/).filter(Boolean)
}

console.log(slicer("0.0000001234"))
console.log(slicer("0.0012345678"))
console.log(slicer("0.0000123456"))
console.log(slicer("0.1000123456"))
console.log(slicer("1.1000123456"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regular expression to split when `[1-9]` is found, and capture the remaining part of the string:

```js
const parse = str => {
  const [zeros, digits] = str.split(/([1-9].*)/);
  console.log(zeros, digits);
};

parse("0.0000001234") // => "0.000000", "1234" 
parse("0.0012345678") // => "0.00", "12345678"
parse("0.0000123456") // => "0.0000", "123456"
```

Comment: I've never known using `regex` with `split()`. but I think it is the perfect answer.